# Is it allowed to inherit from a class in the std namespace (namely std::wstring)?

Tags: c++, gcc, stl, g++

The class std::wstring is missing some operations for "normal" c strings (and literals).

I would like to add these missing operations in my own custom class:

```
#include <string>

class CustomWString : public std::wstring {

        public:

            CustomWString(const char*);
            const char* c_str(void);
};
```

The code above compiles fine on Ubuntu Karmic with g++ v4.4.1.

But I am wondering if there are arguments against doing so?

**EDIT:** some examples to clarify what I mean with "missing operations" :

```
std::wstring foo("hello"); // requires the L() macro or something like that
std::string bar("hello");
std::wstring goose(bar.c_str());

foo="hello";  // requires the L() macro
foo=bar.c_str();
foo=bar;
```

**EDIT:** I would like to have this somehow "centralized". That's because I have a project to be ported from M$-Windows with thousand's of these failing operations.

The nice thing is: there is one central place where the string type to be used is defined, e.g.:

```
#ifdef WINDOWS_OS
    typedef std::wstring AppStringClass;
#else
    typedef std::string AppStringClass;
#endif
```

Comment: What are the missing operations?

Comment: @GMan:  Conversions to and from `char*`, I presume.

Comment: If that's it, deriving from an entire string class seems overkill. What's wrong with two functions?

Comment: I strongly recommend putting the conversion routines outside the class. It's not that much work writing `std::wstring str = encode("str");`. Also, drop that `void` in your snippet, it is completely useless there.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The compiler definitely lets you, as there is no way to seal a class with a public constructor in C++.

**STL containers are not designed for inheritance**, so it's generally a bad idea. C++ has to many strange corners to ignore that. Your derived class might break with another STL implementation, or just with an update of the build environment.

However, I'd consider it a striong warning sign, not a total no-go. It's a "are you really really sure what you are doing, do you know all implications, and have good arguments against all alternatives"?

**In your case:** Providing additional constructors is fine (since the public interface is documented and you can replicate that), and as long as you are not introducing new data members or a VMT, slicing or non-virtual destructor is not a problem. (Keep in mind though that the C++ standard claim undefined behavior when deleting through a base class pointer without virtual DTor)

**However** I am not sure how you want to implement `char const * c_str()` without also providing storage for the string. And as soon as you introduce new data members, you are entering a field of landmines.

Comment: you are right regarding "how to implement c_str() without providing local storage".

Comment: `there is no way to seal a class with a public constructor in C++` - for posterity, there is in >= C++11, which added the `final` keyword for both classes and virtual methods. I'm guessing no extant stdlib implementation has actually made any stdlib classes `final`, though, since (A) the Standard presumably does not stipulate it and/because (B) it would break all sorts of code already (perhaps unnecessarily or even dangerously) inheriting from stdlib classes.

Answer (score 15):

It is legal, but many people think it undesirable. The issue is that the standard library template classes do not have virtual destructors. So if you ever write code like this:

```
std::wstring * p = new CustomWString ;
...
delete p;
```

you have undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

I think you know that `basic_string` doesn't define a virtual destructor. It is WRONG to use `wstring` in a *polymorphic* manner. Otherwise, you can use your custom class as usual.

So, the following is hazardous:

```
vector<wstring*> mystrings;
mystrings.push_back(new CustomWString);
...
delete mystrings[0]; // No virtual destructor
```

Using your custom class directly is OK, e.g.

```
vector<CustomWString> mystrings; // OK
mystrings.push_back("...");
```

Answer (score 3):

The traditional argument against inheriting from STL objects is they do not have a virtual destructor. So, take vector for example. If I were to inherit from it:

```
  class CMyVect : public std::vector<int>
  {
      ...
     int* someMemory;
  public:
     CMyVect()
     {
        someMemory = new int();
     }

     ~CMyVect()
     {
        delete someMemory;
     }
  };
```

The non virtual destructor in the base class means that if the user of this points a ponter-to-vector-of-ints to a CMyVect then deletes that pointer, your destructor will not be invoked, leaking memory. That is to say:

```
 int main()
 {
     std::vector<int>* vecPtr = new CMyVect();
     delete vecPtr; // invokes vector constructor only, not yours
 }
```

So that's not to say you **can't** inherit from these objects, but it can be frought with this problem. You have to be careful how you use the objects you are inheriting from or alternatively j ust have no need for your destructor to fire (don't hold any resources that need to be freed).

Comment: Lack of a virtual destructor is only only a problem when you introduce new data members. (That's not guaranteed by the standard, but a compiler implementation would have to go out of its way to break this)

Comment: @peterchen: suppose that the derived class has one or more virtual members, and the base class doesn't. Then I'm pretty sure deleting through the base class will go wrong, because (in a typical implementation) it doesn't point to the start of a memory allocation, but the block will be freed as if it did. The compiler isn't going out of its way. I think it's best to advise just to avoid undefined behaviour, rather than try to figure out in what conditions a "reasonable" compiler will in fact do something predictable.

Comment: (Also, the questioner's example does have a new data member).

Comment: @peterchen the standard explicitly says that the lack of a virtual destructor will cause undefined behaviour if a derived object is deleted via a base pointer. The fact that it appears to work does not mean that the behaviour is not undefined.

Comment: @Steve: I'd consider introducing a VMT a new data member in that context - as it changes the in-memory representation. ....   @Neil: that doesn't mean every class needs a virtual DTor. I agree that we are beyond what's sanctioned by the compiler, though.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible, and legal. But it's a bad idea. The classes are not designed for inheritance, and extending them is best done without inheritance. If you are not careful when *using* the classes, you'll get undefined behavior. (The classes don't have virtual destructors)

Moreover, it seems a bad idea to add those specific functions, since they depend on locale and encoding. You're giving the class more than one responsibility. The functionality of converting between `char` and `wchar_t` belongs elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

The class template `std::basic_string` (of which `std::wstring` is a typedef with specific template arguments) does *not* have a virtual destructor, and as such, inheriting from it publicly is *a bad idea*.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it. But I see no point, since std::basic_string
(and its concrete versions std::string and std::wstring)
define no virtual methods and have non-virtual destructor.
So there is no way, you can use your subclass properly in place of e.g. std::wstring.

Comment: Well yeah, they could pass it in-place-of `wstring`, but the caller expecting a `wstring` could only invoke base behaviour, not anything the OP added. This raises the question why such strong(est) coupling as inheritance is used - if there isn't an equally strong rationale, i.e. Liskov substitutability. Inheriting is usually a lazy way to get all methods from the base without forwarding/otherwise wrapping them as needed by composition. But why not (A) do the work, (B) use `public` composition, (C) use free functions? Inheritance has so many potential pitfalls that the benefits have to be large

Answer (score 0):

The ability to "inherit" one class from another is a language feature. It is just a formal, plain and dry language feature that is not tied to any specific aplication or any specific use model. It is a low-level tool that you can use for different purposes. And, to answer your question, it is perfectly legal to inherit from `std::wstring` class.

However, the next question would be the question of "why". Why do you want to inherit from `std::wstring`?

If you are designing your code within the OOP paradigm, then inheriting *publicly* from `std::wstring` might not be a good idea, "might" being a key word here. Public inheritance in OOP usually implies an IS-A relationship in a polymorphic class hierarchy. Class `std::wstring` is not designed to be polymorphic, which is the reason why publicly inheriting from it might be seen as a rather strange thing to do.

If you are designing your code within a different paradigm, like for example template meta-programming one(TMP), then public inheritance might be a perfectly valid thing to do. You see, in TMP public inheritance serves a completely different purpose, not even remotely related to polymorphism and relationships.

In other words, there no way to produce a concrete answer to your question without taking into account the bigger picture. In any case, beware of "mechanical" answers, like "since `std::wstring` has no virtual destructor, you can't inherit from it since it will break *<proceed to illustrate with code>*". Such reasoning is completely bogus, even within the OOP approach.