# right way to return new instances from subclass of C++ string

Tags: c++

I want to extend the C++ string class, returning subclass references (instead of parent string reference), but this code excerpt...

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class mystring : public string
{
public:
 mystring&  left( int cnt )
 {   return  (mystring&)mystring( substr(0,cnt) );
 }
};
```

produces this VS8 compiler error:

> error C2440: '' :
>   cannot convert from
>   'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>'
>   to 'mystring'

What's the right way to declare mystring::left() so the compiler will stop complaining, hopefully also eliminating the cast?

Comment: Please explain why you think you need to subclass std::string like this.

Comment: I'm reusing code that uses MFC CString which has Left, Right and other functions not found in C++ string

Comment: std::string and MFC CString are not compatible. Your best approach is to transform things like mfc.Left(3) into free functions like 
Left( stds, 3).

Comment: The problem with aggregation is that you have to redefine the entire interface of string. Subclassing gets you all of that.  The compiler seems to be happy with:

mystring&  left( int cnt )
{  return (mystring&)substr(0,cnt);  }

Comment: Why do those functions need to be members? Check out the boost string library. Free functions are probably better here.

Comment: I know that std::string and CString aren't compatible... I'm rewriting/reusing source that used CStrings for a service that will have no interface, and hopefully be a bit more portable to Linux.

Comment: @Mike No-one is suggesting aggregation. I am suggesting adding to the std::string interface by writing free (i.e. non-class) functions like Left(s,n) and Righte( s,n) where 's' is std::string const 
reference.

Answer (score 6):

> error C2440: '' : cannot convert from 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>' to 'mystring'

From MSDN page on C2440:

> C2440 can also occur for an incorrect
>   use of a user-defined conversion. For
>   more information on user-defined
>   conversions, see User-Defined
>   Conversions). The following sample
>   generates C2440.

The error you hit is because you are trying to return a base class object via a reference to an object of the derived class. It works the other way well. Hence, your need for the cast -- which is bad.

Standard containers (including `std::string`) are not suitable for inheritance, use aggregation instead.

You don't need the cast to `string&`.

Try something like this:

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class mystring     {
public:
 // create an appropriate conversion op/ctor between string -> mystring
 mystring(string const& s) : impl(s) {}
 mystring  left( int cnt )
 {   
     return mystring( impl.substr(0,cnt) );
 }
 string impl;

};
```

Comment: Taken the example directly still gives *C2440* - mystring is not constructible from `std::string` as it has no constructor that takes std::string or a type it can be converted to.

Comment: Perhaps you should note *why* `std::string` shouldn't be subclassed. E.g., destructors and all of that lovely stuff.

Comment: Sorry dirkgently, but i don't get the continued upvotes: in context of the question it is wrong - the OP is trying to construct an instance of `mystring` from `std::string`, which doesn't work as `mystring` isn't constructible from `std::string`.

Comment: @gf: Ah, I see the typo -- there was a problem in the `left()` implementation. However, I pointed out a more basic flaw in the design. As for returning a `mystring` -- it is simply a matter creating an appropriate conversion operator (which I left as an exercise and I should have mentioned). As for the upvotes, I will make no comment but do fix your example.

Comment: Still, you're referring to the C2440, which is given for another reason then you're saying.

Comment: @gf: Updated my post w/ MSDN reference. HTH.

Answer (score 4):

The problem seems to be that `substr` returns a `std::string`, not an instance of your subclass. Do you have a `mystring::mystring(const std::string&)` constructor?

And why on *earth* are you subclassing std::string anyway? :D

It's probably better to write a free function instead of subclassing.

```
#include <string>

namespace mystring {
  std::string left(const std::string& str, int cnt)
  {   
     return str.substr(0,cnt);
  }
}
```

Comment: +1, but remove "probably" ;-) C++ programmers coming from other languages just have to accept that not everything in C++ should be a member function. This is surprisingly difficult to assimilate, even once you see how useful the free functions in <algorithm> are. I found that this article by Herb Sutter helped: http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/084.htm. But in my case, I had been softened up by Python before I reached C++. Non-member `len` will probably always freak me out just a little bit...

Answer (score 3):

be careful when deriving from a class in the std namespace.

see [permalink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1856646/is-it-allowed-to-inherit-from-a-class-in-the-std-namespace-namely-stdwstring/1856689#1856689) to answer for my own question from peterchen.

**EDIT**: the essence of the article referenced by the permalink is: you can derive from std::string. But you  should not introduce a new member variable.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler already tells you what the problem is - it can't convert from `std::string` to `mystring` as your class isn't constructible from `std::string`.

You shouldn't subclass the standard libraries types however, they aren't suited for that - use composition.

If we leave that issue aside for a moment:
You need to supply a constructor that takes a `std::string`. But that still leaves a problem: you're returning a reference to a temporary - just return by value here.

Your class could now look like this:

```
class mystring  
{
    std::string m_string;
public:
    mystring(const std::string& s) : m_string(s) {}

    mystring left(std::string::size_type cnt) {
        return m_string.substr(0,cnt);
    }
};
```